# Please Provide a SQL Script to Query Person that His/Her City Occurs in the Table More Than or Equal to 6

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Below is the customer table in database ABC.
`Person` table:

```
ID  Name    Salary  City
====================================
1   Jack    1000    Singapore
2   Jim     3000    LA
3   Rose    2000    HongKong
?           
100 Tom     5000    New York

(total record = 100)
(Id is Primary Key)
```

The goal is to provide a SQL script to query `Person` that his/her city occurs in the table more than or equal `>=` to `6`.

*Example:*

The number of `Person` that live in `Singapore` is `10`;

The number of `Person` that live in `HongKong` is `5`

The number of `Person` that live in `LA  is`6`.

So in this example the output should be all Person that live in `Singapore` and `LA` only.

My result might be:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE (SELECT City FROM  Person GROUP BY City)>6
```

Maybe there is something wrong. Wish somebody can help me.Thank you.

Comment: We are not here to do your work for you. Either write your own code or let us know how much you're paying.

Comment: Have a look at `Count`, `group by` and `Having` clause

Comment: select * from Person where (Select City from Person group by City having count(*)>6)?

Comment: What it your RDBMS, btw?

Answer (score 1):

I've counted the occurrence of each city in the table using `COUNT` function which I used to get your desired result which outputs the City with occurrence of 6 and above. Try my query:

```
SELECT 
      ID,
      Name,
      Salary,
      A.City 
FROM Person
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT City,Count(City) CityCount FROM Person GROUP BY City)B 
ON A.City=B.City WHERE CityCount >= 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the anti-join patterns with a temporary table with the listed cities that are fitting your condition :

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM Person p 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT City 
            FROM Person 
            GROUP BY City 
            HAVING COUNT(*) >= 6
) t ON t.City = p.City
WHERE t.City IS NOT NULL
```